# recover/restore files with specific extension from Time Machine with OSX

Tags: time-machine, backup, data-recovery

I would like to recover/restore only `*.GIF` files from my most recent backup. They were accidentally deleted from everywhere in `My Computer` instead of just the intended folder. I currently have only 6 GB of free space (they took up about 1 GB, and only ~4000 files).

If I try selecting the most recent backup in Time Machine for recover, it starts by counting up to >20,000 files and then quits saying there is not enough space and stops. If I try to specify the Users folder, and `kind:GIF` in the most recent backup in Time Machine, the files remain gray color and not selectable.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this not possible?

Let me know if more info is needed.

**NOTE:** I edited to change "recover" to "recover/restore" - I didn't stop to think about the difference in meaning. If possible I need them back where they belong and there were so many locations - including applications and webpage downloads - I doubt I could figure it out myself.

Here is my most recent backup. Is `Seagate Backup Plus Drive` the drive name? With spaces?

[image: screenshot of backup drive]

```
This seems to work:
david914s-MacBook-Air:Volumes david914$ cd "/Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/Backups.backupdb/"


But adding this, doesn't:
david914s-MacBook-Air:Backups.backupdb david914$ cd "/Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/Backups.backupdb/david914's MacBook Air/"

-bash: cd: /Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/Backups.backupdb/david914's MacBook Air/: No such file or directory
```

---

Hmm... I've deleted `--dry-run` but still it is not adding files back to my computer.

```
david914s-MacBook-Air:david914’s MacBook Air david914$ rsync -av --include=".gif" --include="/" --exclude="*" "/Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/Backups.backupdb/david914’s MacBook Air/2015-08-30-221221/Macintosh HD/Users/david914/" "/Users/david914/"
building file list ... done
./

sent 81 bytes  received 26 bytes  214.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
david914s-MacBook-Air:david914’s MacBook Air david914$
```

Comment: Just noticed: In your code dump it says `--include="/"` and should be `--include="*/"`

Comment: Same for `--include=".gif"` - should be `--include="*.gif"`

Comment: There is further discussion of that possessive apostrophe [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/204300/143729)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you will have to use the Terminal:

1. Mount your Time Machine disk. It will be located in `/Volumes/myTMdisk/`.
2. Start the Terminal
3. Type **`rsync -av --dry-run --include="*.gif" --include="*/" --exclude="*" /Volumes/myTMdisk/Backups.backupdb/myMac/Latest/myDisk/Users/me/ /Users/me/Desktop/allmygifs/`**

   - Replace `myTMdisk`, `myMac`, `myDisk`, `me`, and `/Users/me/Desktop/allmygifs/` with the appropriate values.
   - You can use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key  while typing to auto-complete your path.
   - If your pathname contains whitespaces or special characters, put it in quotes, e.g. `rsync -av --dry-run --include="*.gif" --include="*/" --exclude="*" "/Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/Backups.backupdb/david914’s MacBook Air/2015-08-30-221221/Macintosh HD/Users/david914/" "/Users/david914/Desktop/allmygifs/"`
   - If you want to restore the files into the original locations, use `rsync -av --dry-run --include="*.gif" --include="*/" --exclude="*" /Volumes/myTMdisk/Backups.backupdb/myMac/Latest/myDisk/Users/me/ /Users/me/`. **I would recommend another backup before doing that.** Then replace `Latest` with the respective timestamp.
   - In case you get file permission errors (e.g. `Permission denied` and `code 23` error as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/30676)), you may have to use `sudo` in front of `rsync`. **But now you will really need to backup first. Ideally backup to a different disk or make another copy of your TM disk.**
4. Once you are sure everything works, remove the `--dry-run` argument after `rsync -av` to actually write files.
5. Enjoy!

Comment: So @n1000 does this just copy all of them into a single folder I specify? I'm trying to recover/restore them to their original locations - the way that I'm hoping TIme Machine knows how to do (see update). So one **can not** do extension-specific restores with Time Machine? There are GIFs all over the place,

Comment: I did not find a way to do it directly in TM. My filters actually do not work there. Also I am not sure if you could restore recursively, i.e. into the corresponding folders.

Comment: Tried `--dry-run` got this, which I'm guessing might be OK? `sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]` will take your wise advice and do a backup now before executing. Thank you very much @n1000 !!!

Comment: added autocomplete and cd results at bottom of question - bitten by the single quote maybe?

Comment: Yes - it's the single quote your path contains `’` not `'` in `david914’s MacBook Air`

Comment: You're welcome. See also my comment to your question above. You should get warnings in the output if files are skipped due to permission errors. One question at a time - just use `tab` ;)

Comment: DONE!! :)  I think I should try to tidy up my question a bit? But that will have to wait a half-day,  ditto my previous thanks @n1000. For the record: `sent 1502930485 bytes  received 42564 bytes  17999677.23 bytes/sec
total size is 2536747693  speedup is 1.69`

Comment: Great!! Glad it worked. Yes - might be helpful for others to clean up comments and question.

Comment: There is further discussion of that possessive apostrophe [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/204300/143729)