# What character is this possessive apostrophe: ’

Tags: macos, filesystem

In a [recent answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/203161/9058) I needed to include a a possessive apostrophe in a path name within Time Machine for a command line operation. I have it saved in a text file, but what the heck is it? I don't see it on my keyboard.

`"/Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/Backups.backupdb/david914’s MacBook Air/2015-08-30-221221/Macintosh HD/Users/david914/"`

I first tried to look at it with python, but no luck.

These I know:

```
things = ["'", '"', "`"]
names = ["single quote", "double quote", "backtick"]
ascii = [ord(thing) for thing in things]

for (a, b, c) in zip(things, ascii, names):
    print "  " + a  + "  " + str(b) + "  " + c

  '  39  single quote
  "  34  double quote
  `  96  backtick
```

but the apostrophe in question is: -->  ’  <--

and all I can get is:

```
>>> ord("’")
Unsupported characters in input
```

Then I used Excel:

```
=CODE("’")
```

and got:

[image: Excel code for a character]

Checking the opposite direction in Excel:

```
=CHAR(213)
```

[image]

Back to python:

```
>>> chr(213)
'\xd5'
```

Does this character appear normally on English MacBook Air keyboards? How else can I make them besides resorting to some kind of Office or Open Office product ?? What it is, anyway?

Comment: char 213 (decimal) or d5 (hex) is the right single quote represented in the old MacRoman character set.  OS X uses Unicode, where it is U+2019.  From the keyboard this is normally made via option shift ]

Comment: Thanks @TomGewecke ! That is in fact an alternate answer - *what the heck is this thing and how can I make more of them?*

Comment: Does it not work to make them using option shift ]    ?

Comment: I meant that as a compliment @TomGewecke ! It works perfectly! I wanted to highlight the fact that in 201 characters you both explained what that character is, and gave me a way to easily make more of them. So you actually answered both parts of my question with one sentence. Great!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Section 6.2 of the Unicode Standard 7.0.0 states:

> U+2019 […] is preferred where the character is to represent a punctuation mark, as for contractions: “We’ve been here before.”

The character does not appear directly on any keyboard I own.

On an British or US English keyboard you can use <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to type the character: `’` == `U+2019`; thanks to @tom-gewecke for this key combination.

## Emoji & Symbols Palette

In OS X 10.10, you can access this character from the menu item: **Edit > Emoji & Symbols**:

[image: Character Palette]

Control-Click on the character to copy additional information.

In earlier versions of OS X, this palette was called the [Character Palette](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/keyboards/charpalosx.html).

### Smart Quotes

The character `’` is can be [automatically substituted](http://www.imore.com/how-turn-smart-quotes-mavericks) by OS X through the **Smart Quotes** feature of the default text system:

[image: Smart Quotes screenshot]

### Unicode is Complex

Copying and pasting a few of the candidate character information to a text file results in:

- `'` - APOSTROPHE, Unicode: U+0027, UTF-8: 27
- `ʼ` - MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE, Unicode: U+02BC, UTF-8: CA BC
- `՚` - ARMENIAN APOSTROPHE, Unicode: U+055A, UTF-8: D5 9A
- `＇` - FULLWIDTH APOSTROPHE, Unicode: U+FF07, UTF-8: EF BC 87

Ted Clancy's article [Which Unicode character should represent the English apostrophe? (And why the Unicode committee is very wrong.)](https://tedclancy.wordpress.com/2015/06/03/which-unicode-character-should-represent-the-english-apostrophe-and-why-the-unicode-committee-is-very-wrong/) reveals just how involved the unicode character set can become.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for putting all of that in one place. I am relieved to see that my question was at least not trivial. After reading all of that, I am hesitant to use the possessive form or contractions ever again, lest I use the wrong character and Ted finds out about it! :)

Comment: Good to hear the answer helped. Internationalisation is a difficult problem to tackle.

Comment: The US keyboard makes U+2019 via option shift ]